# Update pandas column values if they are equal to another column's value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing account IDs, home, work, and mobile phone numbers. All of these values are strings. My goal is to update the values of each row such that all duplicate numbers both within the same row and across different rows are set to NaN, leaving one 'original' number. How can I accomplish this in an efficient way?

When updating values in the same row, priority is given to home phone first and then work phone second. So if `home == work == mobile`, both work and mobile are updated to NaN. If `home != work == mobile`, then mobile is updated to NaN. When updating values in different rows, it does not matter which duplicate phone number is kept as the 'original' number. For example, if `A['home'] == B['mobile'] == C['work']`, two of those values should be set to NaN and the remaining one remain unchanged. I have chosen to keep the first number and set the other duplicate numbers to NaN when displaying the dataframe.

I've figured out how to update values within the same row using `df.loc`, but I've been unsuccessful in figuring out how I can also accomplish updating duplicate values to NaN across different rows and columns. How can I achieve this?

Below is further information on what I'm trying to do and where I'm getting stuck:

My initial dataframe looks something like this:

```
acct_id        home        work      mobile
      A  1111111111  1111111111  1111111111
      B  2222222222  2222222222  2222222222
      C  3333333333  3333333333  3333333333
      D  4444444444  5555555555  5555555555
      E  6666666666  7777777777  8888888888
      F  9999999999  9999999999  8888888888
      G  7777777777  6666666666  5555555555
      H  4444444444  3333333333  2222222222
      I         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

and my goal is to update the dataframe so that it looks like this:

```
acct_id        home        work      mobile
      A  1111111111         NaN         NaN
      B  2222222222         NaN         NaN
      C  3333333333         NaN         NaN
      D  4444444444  5555555555         NaN
      E  6666666666  7777777777  8888888888
      F  9999999999         NaN         NaN
      G         NaN         NaN         NaN
      H         NaN         NaN         NaN
      I         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

I'm currently approaching this as a 2 step problem. Step 1 is removing duplicate numbers in the same row. Step 2 is removing duplicate numbers across different rows and different columns.
I have figured out step 1, using the `df.loc` command:

```
df.loc[df['home'] == df['work'], ['work']] = np.nan
df.loc[df['home'] == df['mobile'], ['mobile']] = np.nan
df.loc[df['work'] == df['mobile'], ['mobile']] = np.nan
```

This is what my dataframe looks like after running the above commands:

```
acct_no        home        work      mobile
      A  1111111111         NaN         NaN
      B  2222222222         NaN         NaN
      C  3333333333         NaN         NaN
      D  4444444444  5555555555         NaN
      E  6666666666  7777777777  8888888888
      F  9999999999         NaN  8888888888
      G  7777777777  6666666666  5555555555
      H  4444444444  3333333333  2222222222
      I         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

However, I can't wrap my head around step 2. As a brute force method, I have found that I can sort the dataframe on home and then loop through each row, checking if the previous row's home value is the same as the current row's, setting the current row's value to nan if it is the same. Lastly, I would have to repeat that process for the work and mobile keys. This is what the code for checking the home field would look like:

```py
df.sort_values(by='home', inplace=True)
prev_row = {'home':None,'work':None,'mobile':None}
    for cur_idx,cur_row in df.iterrows():
        if prev_row['home'] == cur_row['home']:
            cur_row['home'] = np.nan
        prev_row = cur_row
```

After running the above code just for updating and checking on the home column, my dataframe will look like this:

```
acct_no        home        work      mobile
      A  1111111111         NaN         NaN
      B  2222222222         NaN         NaN
      C  3333333333         NaN         NaN
      D  4444444444  5555555555         NaN
      E         NaN  3333333333  2222222222
      F  6666666666  7777777777  8888888888
      G  7777777777  6666666666  5555555555
      H  9999999999         NaN  8888888888
      I         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

This solution is pretty hacky and not efficient for larger datasets, so how can I achieve this in a more efficient manner?

Any help is greatly appreciated -- thank you in advance!

Comment: You de-duped within the row in step one, great! Now you want to de-dip across rows.  Recall the SQL coalesce function. Synthesize a new column by coalescing across home, work, mobile. Good. Now you have a sort key. Compute sorted values, which happens very quickly. Use that to either delete duplicate rows, or to set the three phone numbers to NAN.

Comment: @J_H Thanks for the advice! If you make your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: OK. Also, Stack Overflow encourages self answers. I would be very happy to see you implement the suggestions, and post your own answer, which includes the technical details of the code.

Comment: @J_H If I were to coalesce the home, work, and mobile columns into a new column, wouldn't it take the first number it finds (like combine_first method)? Perhaps combining the home, work, and mobile numbers into a new column stored as an array and unnesting that would make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might address your step 2 needs.
If not, feel free to go with another approach.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        dict(acct_no="D", home="4444444444", work="5555555555"),
        dict(acct_no="E", home=np.NaN, work="3333333333", mobile="2222222222"),
        dict(acct_no="J", home=np.NaN, work=np.NaN, mobile="8888888888"),
        dict(acct_no="K", home=np.NaN, work="8888888888"),
        dict(acct_no="L", home=np.NaN, work=np.NaN, mobile="8888888888"),
    ]
)
df["phone"] = (df.home
               .combine_first(df.work)
               .combine_first(df.mobile))
df = (df.sort_values(by="phone")
      .drop_duplicates(subset="phone")
      .set_index("acct_no"))
print(df)
```

output

```
               home        work      mobile       phone
acct_no                                                
E               NaN  3333333333  2222222222  3333333333
D        4444444444  5555555555         NaN  4444444444
J               NaN         NaN  8888888888  8888888888
```

In this implementation we are *only* looking at the `phone` column, which is the preferred number for an account.
That might be a bit more draconian that desired.
Notice for example that accounts "K" and "L" were nuked entirely,
on the basis of sharing a phone number with "J".
If multiple customers share a Home land line,
that might not be the desired business logic.
Notice also that if "K" were to add a Home
number of 7878787878 he would survive,
despite the 8888888888 dup.
If Mobile is "more unique" than Home,
perhaps we should prefer that number.

Now that we have used the `phone` column
to good advantage, feel free to .drop() it.

The sort costs O(N log N),
and everything else is linear,
so this should be a performant solution,
even for large datasets.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as to how this works! I like that it is a linear and performant solution, however, dropping entire rows is not a desired effect, so I'll have to look at more than just the `phone` column, it appears.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the simplest would be to [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the numbers as Series, [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) and then restore the original shape:

```
out = (df.set_index('acct_id').stack()
         # the magic happens here
         .mask(lambda d: d.duplicated())
         # restore original format
         .unstack().reset_index()
       )
```

Alternative:

```
out = (df.set_index('acct_id')
         .stack().drop_duplicates().unstack()
         .reindex(df['acct_id']).reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)
      )
```

Output:

```
  acct_id        home        work      mobile
0       A  1111111111         NaN         NaN
1       B  2222222222         NaN         NaN
2       C  3333333333         NaN         NaN
3       D  4444444444  5555555555         NaN
4       E  6666666666  7777777777  8888888888
5       F  9999999999         NaN         NaN
6       G         NaN         NaN         NaN
7       H         NaN         NaN         NaN
8       I         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

##### order: columns first

If you want, you can easily tweak the above to give a column-first preference in the way to chose the duplicates to keep:

```
out = (df.set_index('acct_id').unstack()
         .mask(lambda d: d.duplicated())
         .swaplevel().unstack().reset_index() # or: .unstack().T.reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
  acct_id        home        work      mobile
0       A  1111111111         NaN         NaN
1       B  2222222222         NaN         NaN
2       C  3333333333         NaN         NaN
3       D  4444444444  5555555555         NaN
4       E  6666666666         NaN  8888888888
5       F  9999999999         NaN         NaN
6       G  7777777777         NaN         NaN
7       H         NaN         NaN         NaN
8       I         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Comment: This answer works for me as well as the above answer!

Comment: @Noah I believe this one is more generic (doesn't requires any a priori on the data), but glad you have what you want.